# Pass JSON data to next page in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am a beginner and still learning to react native.

In my react native App, I have 2 screens.
In the first page, I have JSON data [fetched from live server];
I want to pass this JSON data to the next page.

I used react-navigation for navigating between pages.
I passed one data[Mobile number] to the next page.

But I couldn't figure out, how to pass JSON data to next page!

**first-page code : [which contain JSON data]**

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props) 
    this.state = {

    UserMNO: ''
    } 
  }

  UserLoginFunction = () =>{

 const { UserMNO } = this.state;
 const {firstname} = this.state;
 const {lastname} = this.state;
 const {email} = this.state;
 const {profession} =this.state;

fetch('http://demo.weybee.in/react/User_Login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

  mobileno: UserMNO,

      })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson != 'Enter valid phone number' )
        {   

            console.log(responseJson[0]);
            console.log(responseJson[1]);
            console.log(responseJson[2]);
            console.log(responseJson[3]);
            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
            this.refs.toast.show('Login successful', 500, () => {
            const { navigation } = this.props;

            const { UserMNO }  = this.state ;

            navigation.navigate("Profile",
              {mobileno : UserMNO},
              );
    });
        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }
```

**console.log of first page's JSON data**

[image: log of JSON data]

**second-page code: [where I need JSON data]**

```
     <Block flex style={styles.profileCard}>
                <Block middle style={styles.avatarContainer}>
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: Images.ProfilePicture }}
                    style={styles.avatar}
                  />
                </Block>

                <Block flex>

                  <Block middle style={styles.nameInfo}>
                    <Text bold size={28} color="#32325D">
                        {this.props.navigation.getParam("Name")}
                    </Text>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Email id"
                        value={this.props.navigation.getParam("EmailId")}
                        style={{marginTop:20, borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                      <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Mobile Number"
                        value={this.props.navigation.getParam("mobileno")}
                        style={{borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="profession"
                        value={this.props.navigation.getParam("Profe")}
                        style={{borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>

                  </Block>
```

**screenshot of second screen**

[image: Profile page]

**Error**

does not pass anything

Comment: You navigate with the parameter mobileno. It is passed, as you can see the input is filled. The other params are empty because you didn't put it in the navigation parameter, so i don't see where is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send your response JSON like this:

```
navigation.navigate(
              "Profile", 
              {mobileno: UserMNO, myJSON: responseJson} 
);
```

and get it in second screen:

```
const responseJson = this.props.navigation.getParam("myJSON");
```

Comment: @AakashThoriya yes you can pass, and then you will receive the first object of your json array

Comment: finally, data successfully passed! thank you for contributing your precious time